# Redis: Can I save more than 1 value for different keys?

Tags: database, redis

I'd like to save several values for the same key, for example:

`key "value1" "value2" "value3"` and be able to pop the three values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis has a list datatype which you can push to:

```
RPUSH key value1
RPUSH key value2
RPUSH key value3
```

then

```
RPOP key
RPOP key
RPOP key
```

will remove and return the elements in reverse order (i.e. the list is treated as a stack). You can also retrieve elements with `LRANGE` or `LINDEX`.

Have a look through the [online documentation](http://redis.io/commands#list), there is even a live prompt where you can try out the commands if you click on one of the command names.

Answer (score -2):

When use a list

```
{'key': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] }
```

Comment: This answer is misleading - while you may mean a redis list, your syntax suggests a key containing a JSON list, which is correct for memcached, but not for redis. The correct method is to use a redis list - i.e. 3 calls to LPUSH.